# polymorphic tree number of leaves-java

Tags: java, recursion, tree, polymorphism

How would I write a recursive method that returns the number of leaves in a polymorphic tree? This means that I cannot use nodes or null but I have two classes, Nonemptytree and Emptytree, both of which have fields of left and right for left and right subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by 'leaves' you mean the last (deepest) element in a tree that has both left and right nodes as `null`. It's a bit unclear of how the classes `Nonemptytree` and `Emptytree` are interacting in this scenario, so you might have to clarify a little.

Based on the information you provided, you would have to iterate through all the elements in the tree to allow you to count them.

First, keep track of a counter somewhere:

```
int leafCount;
```

You could perform this counting operating through a recursive call:

```
public int leafNumber(Node node) {
    if (node.left != null) {
        leafNumber(node.left);

    } else if (node.right != null) {'
        leafNumber(node.right); 

    } else {
        leafCount++;
    }
}
```

The above method would iterate through the entire tree recursively. Since you said this was polymorphic, I'm guessing `Nonemptytree` and `Emptytree` share a common super class in which case you could use `instanceof` in the `if` statements to identify the leaf:

```
if (node instanceof Emptytree) {
    leafCount++; // if an Emptytree class contains null left and right nodes
}
```